# Ampere's law: the position of amperian loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

Can Amperian loop be taken parallel to current. I.e suppose current is in a circular loop in xy plane. And let the screen you are watching is xy plane . Can we take amperian loop in the same plane.
And find out magnetic field at a point .
[image: see in the image there is a circular loop through which current flows and white one is amperian loop and we have to find magnetic field at point p]

Answer (score 1):

You could, but unclear how this helps you. Ampere's law would, in this case, tell you that
$$ \oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = 0\ ,$$
because you have no current flowing through the closed loop.

I suppose it does tell you there isn't a toroidal field aligned with the Amperian loop.

Comment: You mean through, not inside the loop .i.e current should pass the cross section of a linear closed loop not reside on the same plane

Comment: @Debakant The RHS is $\int \vec{J} \cdot d\vec{A}$, where the surface integral is taken over a (any) surface bounded by the closed loop. This must be zero for the loop and current shown.